# Express website hosted on Azure giving unexpected error

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I'm running very simple express website on Azure shared resource in Australia Southeast region. Website run locally on port 3000 however when deployed to Azure doesnt render at all. When try to run from Azure throws below error

```
node server.js    

events.js:141    
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event    

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen     (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)   
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:21:5)   
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)   
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Server.js looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

console.log(__dirname);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/contact.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port!' + port);
});
```

Not sure what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Something is already using the 3000 port, run a `netstat -l`, it will ouput all listening ports.

Comment: in your Azure check port 3000 maybe it is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure website allows hosting of node.js application via IIS module called iisnode. Please see the [wiki](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki) for iisnode to know it.

Especially note the content below.

> **Minimal changes to node.js application code.** The iisnode module enables hosting of existing HTTP node.js applications with very minimal changes. Typically all that is required is to change the listed address of the HTTP server to one provided by the iisnode module via the process.env.PORT environment variable.

So you don't need to start up the node app via command `node server.js` manually in Kudu Console. Please try to only deploy or update the code via FTP or VS, and directly access the website to check the deployment successfully. You can try to restart the application on Azure portal if it not works.

If you want to check the running process, you can see them in the `Process explorer` of Kudu tool, please see the figure below.

[image]

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: that trick worked! it was an issue with iisnode module. Thanks for your help. Cheers

Comment: great answer! Really helpful

Answer (score 0):

It means the port you are trying to bind the server to is in use. Try another port or close the program using that port on azure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

This may be due to you have already running an instance of node on 3000.
go to terminal interface using ssh connection to your server.invoke this command.

```
   ps -ax | grep Server.js
```

a list of running process will be there like
[image]

get 1257 from there and on terminal

```
 kill 1257
```

now try to run your server again.